# Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

I need to use Selenium to start up Edge and allow sites to be opened in IE mode (with Selenium).

I did do settings -> default browser -> and selected Allow and restarted.
Problem is, Edge starts up fresh every time, so the setting is no longer there.
There should be some sort of EdgeOptions or ExtraCapabilities to set at startup to make this happen
(similar to this which sets the unexpected alert handling:

```
 capabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "ignore");
```

Google search did not really find anything.  It found the Capabilties class, etc, but not what the individual values you can actually set.  Has anyone done this and can help me?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I understand that you want to open a site in the IE mode using Edge Selenium automation code. Correct me if I misunderstand anything.

You could try the sample JAVA code below.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerOptions;

public class IEDriverSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
        ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);

        driver.get("http://www.bing.com");
        WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q"));
        elem.sendKeys("WebDriver", Keys.RETURN);

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Reference:

[Use Internet Explorer Driver to automate IE mode in Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=java)

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I did find that and try it but it did not seem to work.  But ours is a little different it seems.  There is no AddAdditionalCapability but there is a .setCapability("ie.edgechromium", true); Is that a different version?

Comment: I would suggest you try to make a test with the above-posted code and let me know if you face any error messages. You could share the error screenshot here. I would try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: There was no error.  It just still opened in IE, not Edge.  But I did from Java and looks like you are using C#?

Comment: By the way, if I used Edge driver, edge comes up but I get this: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.76 This application requires Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.5 or greater."  For my Edge I can go to default browser and allow to open in IE, but with Selenium that capability is not preserved.  But using code above it still comes up in IE.

Comment: @Tony, It looks like the code is updated. I have shared the latest JAVA code sample by modifying my above answer. I have also included the document link. Could you please try to test the updated code sample? Let me know whether it works for you or not.